# Angular Elements: Get a reference to host web component element

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements

When using Angular Elements, we'd usually have something like this to build an app as a web component:

```js
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {

    ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef): void {
        customElements.define('foo', createCustomElement(AppComponent, {injector: appRef.injector}));
    }
}
```

With the above, when a host tag is inserted in the host application, the relevant DOM fragment looks like this:

```html
...
<foo>
    #shadow-root
        (AppComponent's contents)
```

Is there a way to inject a reference (like `ElementRef`) to the `<foo>` element hosting the web component into `AppComponent`'s constructor?

Comment: ?? isn't that what ``this.getRootNode().host`` does ?? (I ditched Angular when they called 2.0 an _Upgrade_)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the ElementRef injected into the constructor points exactly to that element (the `<foo>` tag), which is a parent to Shadow DOM:

```js
constructor(private readonly el: ElementRef) {
    // el.nativeElement is <foo>
}
```